# How to display Model window at desired location?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a keyboard modal window which is 9*9. And used it fill Sudoku game board.
In android studio , 
to get the location of the button I used the following code

```
_selectedButton=(Button)view;

        int tag=(int)_selectedButton.getTag();
        _currentRow=tag/9;
        _currentCol=tag%9;
int[] location=new int[2];
        _selectedButton.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        _p=new Point();
        _p.x=location[0];
        _p.y=location[1];

        ShowKeyBoard();
```

ShowKeyBoard is like this

```
int offsetX=30;
int offsetY=30;
_popupWindow.showAtLocation(_keyBoardLayout, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, _p.x+offsetX, _p.y+offsetY);
```

After that he selects a key and I dismiss the popup window.

```
public void BtnKey1Pressed(View view)
    {
        _selectedButton.setText("1");
        _popupWindow.dismiss();
    }
```

How can I do that in Xamarin Android.?
Is it possible to get return data like this in xamarin.?

```
int selectedKey=ShowKeyBoard();
```

Comment: Could you please specify your question. To get a return value from ShowKeyboard, you just need to declare it with return value and return a value ;)

Comment: All the code I have written in Java using android studio and I want it in Xamarin android format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to create a quick and dirty implementation of a popupwindow. I assumed you want to show your popup on the button you just clicked, that's why I used ShowAsDropDown. I left the GetLocationOnScreen code in, you just have to pass it through for example.

```
public sealed class MyPopup : PopupWindow
{
    private readonly Action<int> _callbackMethod;

    private MyPopup(Activity context, Action<int> callbackMethod)
        : base(context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Popup, null),
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
    {
        _callbackMethod = callbackMethod;
    }

    public static Task<int> GetNumber(Activity mainActivity, Button button)
    {
        var t = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
        var popupWindow = new MyPopup(mainActivity, i => t.TrySetResult(i));
        popupWindow.Show(button);
        return t.Task;
    }

    private void Show(View anchor)
    {
        SetActionForChildButtons(anchor, View_Click);
        ShowAsDropDown(anchor);
    }

    private void SetActionForChildButtons(View parent, EventHandler e)
    {
        var button = parent as Button;
        if (button != null)
        {
            button.Click += e;
            return;
        }

        var viewGroup = parent as ViewGroup;
        if (viewGroup == null)
            return;

        for (var i = 0; i < viewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var view = viewGroup.GetChildAt(i);
            SetActionForChildButtons(view, e);
        }
    }

    private void View_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = sender as Button;
        if (button == null)
            return;

        int number;
        if (int.TryParse(button.Text, out number))
            _callbackMethod?.Invoke(number);

        Dismiss();
    }
}
```

With this you can get a number for your field somehow like this

```
private async void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as Button;
    if (button == null)
        return;
    var location = new int[2];
    button.GetLocationOnScreen(location);
    var number = await MyPopup.GetNumber(this, button);
    button.Text = number.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. While above code not worked for me I created something similar from the above answer. I have one problem though , If I click on last row button then popup will not show because it is out of bounds. How can I make it to show Up instead of below if popup is going to be out of bounds?

Comment: Since you have the location and actually the height of your popup, I would propose to check if location+height is greater than height of your layout. But then you probably can use ShowAtLocation